# How to input noise values in dBFS for ffmpeg silence detect

Tags: ffmpeg, audio, noise

I used the silencedetect of ffmpeg with noise value of **-30dB** to get the silent parts of a small video file & used those timestamps to trim & re-encode the silent parts of the videos.

I had used the audio peak meter in Shotcut(a video editor software) to see that anything below **-30dB** can be considered as silence.

When I opened re-encoded output video file in Shotcut, I saw that there were still some sections of video that were below -30dB & longer than the silence duration value I had passed into the ffmpeg command.

On closer inspection, I realized that the audio peak meter shown in Shotcut measures in **dBFS** & the noise value I entered in ffmpeg is in **dB**.

My knowledge of audio signal is very basic & hence I looked up what's **dBFS**. I understood that **dBFS** stands for dB Full Scale & is somehow related to the maximum possible volume in a **WAV** format.

My question is, how to pass the value in **dBFS** to ffmpeg instead of in **dB**?
I checked the ffmpeg documentation & it does not say that we can pass values in **dBFS**.

Comment: dBFS is same as dB, make sure that shotcut is displaying correct info and also that your app that trims stuff is actually correct.

Comment: @PaulB.Mahol Nope, you're wrong. Check also here where OP already asked the same question: https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/50418/how-to-input-noise-values-in-dbfs-for-ffmpeg-silence-detect

Comment: I'm not wrong, It is easy to post false information today.

Comment: @PaulB.Mahol there's no app, I just used the timestamps derived from silencedetect filter into a second ffmpeg command that did the trimming. So, there isn't much chance for error other than manual data entry errors. I checked there weren't any of those errors.